# Blender 2.80 system Req + GPU req

Tags: gpu, system

Can someone please let me know the **minimum system requirements** and **GPU** requirement to run **blender 2.80** and **eevee** smoothly?

Also please let me know the **optimum system requirements** for the purpose of

1. environment modeling
2. Game development
3. charachter modelling and animation

Also if someone can suggest me a good desktop/laptop for personal use that is compatible with blender 2.80 in a **low budget**.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sort of opinion based question is likely to be closed here. Try https://blenderartists.org/ for a more traditional forum.

Comment: Oh ok.. i did not know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender's hardware requirements are documented [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). As of now for Blender 2.80 this is:

> **Minimum**
>
> - 32-bit dual core 2Ghz CPU with SSE2 support
> - 4 GB RAM
> - 1280×768 display
> - Mouse, trackpad or pen tablet
> - Graphics card with 1 GB RAM, OpenGL 3.3
>
> **Recommended**
>
> - 64-bit quad core CPU
> - 16 GB RAM
> - Full HD display
> - Three button mouse
> - Graphics card with 4 GB RAM
>
> **Optimal**
>
> - 64-bit eight core CPU
> - 32 GB RAM
> - Full HD displays
> - Three button mouse and pen tablet
> - Graphics card with +12 GB RAM
>
> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using
>   the GPU requires slightly different requirements. Always make sure to
>   install the latest drivers from the graphics card manufacturer
>   website.
>
> - NVIDIA: GeForce 200 and newer, Quadro Tesla architecture and newer, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all GeForce and Quadro GPUs)
> - AMD: GCN 1st gen and newer (list of all AMD GPUs)
> - Intel: Haswell and newer (list of all Intel GPUs)
> - macOS: version 10.12 or newer with supported hardware

In order to use the GPU for rendering your hardware needs to fulfill the requirements listed in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html). GPU rendering on macOS with AMD graphic cards has been discontinued due to Apple deprecating their OpenCL compiler.

Benchmarking information are available at [Blender Open Data](https://opendata.blender.org/).